# How to fix this error? Fatal error: Call to undefined function ctype_alnum() in .../magento18/lib/Zend/Uri.php on line X?

Tags: php, magento

How to fix this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function ctype_alnum() in /Applications/AMPPS/www/farhom.com/magento18/lib/Zend/Uri.php on line 109

I was trying to run Magento on Ampps on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 20):

Open Ampps Application -> PHP Tab -> PHP Extension -> Select "ctype" -> Apply.

Restart Apache server.

[Forum with answer posts](http://www.softaculous.com/board/index.php?tid=5495&title=running_am_update.app_caused_magenta_site_error_out)

Comment: thanks a lot it worked like a charm and sorry for my silly mistake

Comment: if its the correct answer you could accept them.. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Check to make sure the ctype package is installed; It's typically installed by default but some distros exclude it.

For Alpine:

```
apk add php7-ctype
```